# Qt (QFtp) question

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

Hello i am learning qt and trying to upload a file using QFtp i wrote the folowing code

```
this->connect(this->ftp, SIGNAL(done(bool)), this, SLOT(ftpDone(bool)));
this->connect(this->ftp, SIGNAL(dataTransferProgress(qint64, qint64)), this, SLOT(dataTransferProgress(qint64, qint64)));
this->connect(this->ftp, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(stateChanged(int)));
```

.....

```
if(this->file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
{
    this->ftp->setTransferMode(QFtp::Active);
    this->ftp->connectToHost(this->settings->getHost());
    this->ftp->login(this->settings->getUser(), this->settings->getPassword());
    this->ftp->cd(remoteFilePath);
    this->ftp->get(this->fileName, &this->file);
    this->ftp->close();
}
```

and it kind of stops it reports in dataTransferProgress that it is at 0/XXX but the slot is never invoked again (using the same code but with the get function i can download a file and it works without a problem) also the error that i get after the time out is QFtp::UnknownError.

Comment: I had a very similar problem with yours, and spend many hours on it. This is the most precious thing I learned: You should get used to Qt style programming, i.e make everything event driven and object oriented as possible. You will be happy =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the commands until `get` are successful, it's likely that you are closing the connection before `get` finishes. You should save the identifier returned by `get` and call `close` when the `commandFinished` signal is called with that identifier.

Note: Except `setTransferMode` all of the methods you used are asynchronous. They will be executed in the order that they are called, but since you aren't performing any error checking, it's possible for one to fail and the rest will still be attempted which might result in some confusion.

The proper way of doing this is to `connectToHost` first, if that's successful (you can track this with the `commandFinished` signal) call `login` etc.

Comment: I agree, what you need to to is to build a state engine that reacts to the result (commandFinished) and then triggers the next command.

Comment: i am doing something like this : 
void FtpCore::stateChanged(int state)
{
 switch(state)
 {
 case QFtp::Unconnected:
  std::cout << "Not connected" << std::endl; 
  break;
 .....

 }
}
and the final state reported is QFtp::LoggedIn after that the slot 
void FtpCore::dataTransferProgress(qint64 done, qint64 total)
{
 std::cout << done << "/" << total << std::endl;
} 
is called but only once and then it freezes untill a timeout

Comment: I can't quite understand the code but I think the original problem remains - you are calling `close` before `get` finishes.